# scale_x_discrete() changes y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set up a plot object and add data to it later. I am going to set up the two years of an election cycle and add in vertical lines at the point where key events happened. But my attempt to put vertical lines on the plot at six month intervals has instead put lines the y axis.

```
library(ggplot2)


dateline = seq(as.Date("2011/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 24) 
values = rnorm(24)


events = data.frame(dateline, values)


ggplot(events, aes(x=dateline, y=values))  + 
   scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("2011-01-01","2011-07-01","2012-01-01","2012-07-01")) + 
   labs(x="2012 Election Cycle")
```

The result is: 
[image]

Now I think the lines should be on the x axis and be running up and down, no? And what is even stranger is that using scale_y_continuous() results in the behavior that I was expecting for x.

[image]

What makes this more confusing is that I was following a tutorial pretty closely where scale_x_discrete() behaves in the way I was expecting, i.e., creating vertical lines for the x axis. Am I losing my mind?

http://sharpsightlabs.com/blog/2014/11/24/r-line-chart-and-datavis-process/

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly (and also load the `ggplot2` package. To your question: You are forcing a discrete scale on numeric values, which does not work (dates are integer values, i.e. number of days from 1970-01-01 I think). You may want something like `ggplot(events, aes(x=as.character(dateline), y=values)) + scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("2011-01-01","2011-07-01","2012-01-01","2012-07-01"))`or `ggplot(events, aes(x=dateline, y=values)) + scale_x_date(breaks=as.Date(c("2011-01-01","2011-07-01","2012-01-01","2012-07-01"))) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a continuous scale.  This works for me:

```
ggplot(events, aes(x=dateline, y=values)) +     
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="6 months")
```

More generally, simply:

```
ggplot(events, aes(x=dateline, y=values))
```

Will work in your case because the date range is such that `ggplot` automatically picks 6 months as the range of labels to show (this is why the y continuous scale example works for you; the y thing isn't doing anything, it is the removal of the `scale_x_discrete` bit that helps out).

Comment: Ah, thanks. That makes sense. I thought I was losing my mind.